# Not all close reasons that have been voted on appear in the banner

Tags: support, bug, closing

When I reviewed [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/close/19792), there was one vote for "unclear what you're asking" and one vote for "off topic because ... Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design."

However, the banner on top said:

> Should this question be closed as **unclear what you're asking**?

Before the close reasons change, that would've been:

> Should this question be closed as **unclear what you're asking** or **off topic**?

Is this by-design or a bug?

Comment: I believe  you get the custom off topic messages after two people have voted for the same message. Otherwise, you just get the generic message.

Comment: @W5VO that would've been changed then. Also: there was one vote on both, so following your reasoning I shouldn't have seen "unclear what you're asking", right? Or do I misunderstand you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, this would be an important fix.

As covered in the system-wide blog, the recent revision to the closing mechanism was intended to result in messages which could meaningful educate users as to what specifically was wrong, and wherever possible, what improvement could rescue the question.

Unfortunately, habits die hard, and a lot of close votes are being cast where the claimed reason is more convenient for the closer, than educationally descriptive for the closee.  Having all the voted choices shown on the question would increase the chance that at least one  accurately and usefully informative message is displayed, even if accompanied by the noise of convenience votes.

Comment: You can't possibly know what are convenience votes.  The system may have guidelines for voting criteria, but in the end each of us gets to decide whether or not to cast a vote for whatever reasons we feel are appropriate.  The new system has made things worse by making it more tedius to cast a vote than before.  Chosing something vaguely descriptive is the cost of making the volunteers jump thru more hoops.  But again, you have no way to know if this happens, how much it happens, or which votes are shortcuts and which ones are just disagreements with your narrow view.

Comment: You are welcome to leave the close voting to those willing to do so in accordance with the site **rules**.  The internet has an infinite supply of people who do not meet your **personal standards**, so *you can never win*, but while you continue to act in contravention to the rules and guidelines, we all *lose*.

Comment: The point is you have no right to claim that certain votes are "noise" and "convenience" votes because you have no way to know who voted how for what reason. Similarly, you can't tell me how to vote, nor do you know how I voted in particular cases. You need to get off your high horse.  Note that I said nothing here about how I vote in general or how I voted in particular cases.

Comment: Except that you've publicly admitted to misusing the voting process in these ways.

Comment: I am not misusing anything.  I vote as I see fit.